# Source adding items to queue, signalled back when items have been completed

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

Is there a way in Reactor to from one pipeline add an item into a queue, having another thread/Flux take items from that queue, and have the original pipeline wait for the other thread to have completed the processing of that item?

And I need something similar to this, since there can be many different sources, but I want/need a centralized pipeline for backpressure, retry, and so on.

I have something right now that "works" but it involves lots of threads and usage of Semaphores. The different pipelines also lose context between each other, so future things like reactive transactions won't work well.

A "working" version of what I am sort-of using currently is this:

```
  public class Source {

    private final Queue queue = new Queue();

    public Flux<String> produce() {
      return Flux.range(0, 10)
          .doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("Before queue processed: " + v))
          .flatMap(this.queue::enqueue)
          .doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("After queue processed: " + v));
    }
  }

  public class Queue {

    private class WorkEntry {
      int number;
      String word;
      Throwable exception;
      final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
    }

    private final LinkedBlockingQueue<WorkEntry> blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    public Mono<String> enqueue(int number) {

      return Mono.just(number)
          .flatMap(n -> {

            final var entry = new WorkEntry();
            entry.number = number;

            this.blockingQueue.add(entry);
            return Mono.just(entry);
          })
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
          .flatMap(entry -> {

            try {

              // block until drain() has finished processing item
              entry.semaphore.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // 'word' has been set inside drain() processing
            return Mono.just(entry.word);
          });
    }

    public void drain() {

      Flux
          .<WorkEntry>generate(sink -> {

            final var entry = blockingQueue.poll();
            if (entry == null) {
              sink.complete();
            } else {
              sink.next(entry);
            }
          })
          .flatMap(entry -> Mono.just(entry)
              .flatMap(e -> Mono.just(e.number + "!"))
              .onErrorResume(ex -> {
                entry.exception = ex;
                return Mono.empty();
              })
              .doOnSuccess(word -> {
                entry.word = word;
                entry.semaphore.release(1);
              }))
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
          .subscribe();
    }
  }

  public class Runner {

    public void run() {

      final var source = new Source();

      source.produce()
          .subscribe();

      source.queue.drain();
    }
  }
```

Which will print:

```
Before queue processed: 0
...
Before queue processed: 9
After queue processed: 0!
...
After queue processed: 9!
```

Far from how it works in my code, of course. But I guess the gist of it is understandable?

How do I make this better?

How do I avoid using a blocking call inside `.flatMap`?

How do I avoid spinning up so many elastic threads?

How do I keep the context the same all the way through?

Rewrite it into having one Flux that pulls from the different sources? Problem here, though, would be that it makes it harder to write simpler test cases where I make a source push items, and know when that specific source is done.

**EDIT**: I have found a better way of handling this, without the Semaphore lock. Not perfect, but much better. This is possible by using `delayUntil` and Sinks to communicate between source and queue.

```
  ...

  public class Queue {

    private class WorkEntry {
      int number;
      final Sink.One<String> sink;
    }

    private final LinkedBlockingQueue<WorkEntry> blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    public Mono<String> enqueue(int number) {

      return Mono.just(number)
          .flatMap(n -> {

            final var entry = new WorkEntry();
            entry.number = number;
            entry.sink = Sink.one();

            this.blockingQueue.add(entry);
            return Mono.just(entry);
          })
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
          .delayUntil(e -> e.sink.asMono())
          .flatMap(e -> e.sink.asMono());
    }

    public void drain() {

      Flux
          .<WorkEntry>generate(sink -> {

            final var entry = blockingQueue.poll();
            if (entry == null) {
              sink.complete();
            } else {
              sink.next(entry);
            }
          })
          .flatMap(entry -> Mono.just(entry)
              .flatMap(e -> Mono.just(e.number + "!"))
              .doOnError(t -> entry.sink.tryEmitError(t))
              .doOnSuccess(word -> entry.sink.tryEmitValue(word))
          )
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
          .subscribe();
    }
  }

...
```

This is possible since `.asMono()` of a `Sink.one()` returns the same instance every time it is called. So we can use it both for a delay, and to return the result inside a `.flatMap()`.

Comment: Now that i see your implementation i understand what you are going for and i can straight out tell you that what you basically want to do is to block until something is processed. The entire purpose of reactive programming is that ANY thread can pick up where ANY thread left off, and what you want to do basically defeats that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If your queue does not have an asynchronous api, you can use one of these Mono methods:

```java
// when async api returns some kind of readable value 
Mono<Integer> integerMono = Mono.fromCallable(() -> someBlockingService.getNextIntegerValue)
    .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Error while calling someBlockingService", throwable));

// when async api returns void
Mono<Void> voidMono = Mono.fromRunnable(() -> someBlockingService.doSomething()
    .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Error while calling someBlockingService", throwable));
```

There are even more `Mono.from()` methods to wrap other kinds of sources like `Future` or `CompletionStage`into a Mono.

With this, adding to the queue in an async way is very simple:

```java
        return Mono.just(number)
                .flatMap(n -> {
                    final var entry = new WorkEntry();
                    entry.number = number; // why do you need this line?
                    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> this.blockingQueue.add(entry))
                            .filter(added -> added)
                            .then(Mono.just(entry));
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
```

If add() returns a `false`, the Mono will complete empty. But you can return a default entry by using `switchIfEmpty()`.

**Waiting for semaphore.acquire()**

This is more complicated.

```java
.flatMap(entry -> {

            try {

              // block until drain() has finished processing item
              entry.semaphore.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // 'word' has been set inside drain() processing
            return Mono.just(entry.word);
          });
```

Code inside a `flatMap()` should respond within a *"reasonable amount of time"*™️. Spring Webflux has timeouts and if the acquisition of the semaphore takes longer that the timeout allows, an error will be emitted.

You could try to use zipWith() and retry()

```java
       return Mono.just(number)
                .flatMap(n -> {
                    final var entry = new WorkEntry();
                    entry.number = number; // why do you need this line?
                    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> this.blockingQueue.add(entry))
                            .filter(added -> added) // continue only if entry was added to queue
                            .zipWith(Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
                                try {
                                    entry.semaphore.acquire();
                                    return entry.word;
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    log.error("error while waiting for semaphore", e);
                                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                                }
                                throw new IllegalStateException("Could not acquire a semaphore in time");
                            }));
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .retry(10)
                .map(hasSemaphoreAndEntry -> {
                    Boolean hasSemaphore = hasSemaphoreAndEntry.getT1(); // always true
                    String word = hasSemaphoreAndEntry.getT2();
                    return word;
                })

                .doOnNext( word-> log.info("received {}", word)
```

**Your other questions**

*How do I make this better?*

- Try to get rid of the Semaphores if possible. Some event-driven implementation will work way better with Webflux.

*How do I avoid using a blocking call inside .flatMap?*

- As shown above, try one of the `Mono.from()` methods.

*How do I avoid spinning up so many elastic threads?*

- Waiting for something is always problematic with WebFlux. Moving to an event driven implementation is more natural to the reactive WebFlux approach. But this would be an architectural change for the whole application, I think.

*How do I keep the context the same all the way through?*

- I'm not sure if I understand this question correctly. If the entry is the object that holds your context, always make it the return value of the consecutive map(), zipWith() and flatMap() calls.

Comment: By context I mean the Reactor context itself. If I want, for example, a test case to be @Transactional, and use a reactive transaction... if my Flux in the test case is separated from the actual processing, then it won't be rolled back after test case is complete, since it will be inside another context/parent transaction.
I will try and look at what you mentioned. But I'm not sure I understand what an event driven implementation entails.